# Javascript loop through DOM

Tags: javascript, html

I have 10 of these divs, with class names one through ten.

```
<div class="grid">
    <div class="one"></div>
    <div class="two"></div>
    <div class="three"></div>
    <div class="four"></div>
    <div class="five"></div>
    <div class="six"></div>
    <div class="seven"></div>
    <div class="eight"></div>
    <div class="nine"></div>
    <div class="ten"></div>
</div>
```

Is there an easy way to create a Javascript loop to do this for each div?

```
const one = document.getElementsByClassName('one')[0]; 
one.style.backgroundImage='url(/images/items/' + year + '/1.jpg)';
```

Comment: Does these divs have any parent div ?

Comment: They share a parent div.

Comment: does it have any class ?

Comment: The parent has a class of `.grid`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop over an array of names.

```
["one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten"]
    .forEach((name, idx)=>
       document.querySelector('.' + name).style.backgroundImage=
         'url(/images/items/' + year + '/' + (idx + 1) + '.jpg)');
```

Comment: Thank you, can I replace the "1" in the image file name with an index?

Comment: Thanks again! Last question - where can I idx++ to start at 1 instead of 0?

Comment: Cheers my friend

Answer (score 1):

Based on the parent div with class `grid` you can get all the divs using `querySelectorAll` and then loop them all with the style you want to add. Like this

```
const parentDiv = document.querySelector('.grid');

const allDivs = parentDiv.querySelectorAll('div');

allDivs.forEach((div, i) => {
  div.style.backgroundImage=`url(/images/items/${year}/${i}.jpg')`;
})
```

One thing to mention here that it will add the style to all the divs inside grid div.

In order to handle that you can add one common class to all the divs inside grid class like this

```
<div class="grid">
    <div class="one common">a</div>
    <div class="two common">b</div>
    <div class="three common">c</div>
    <div class="four common">d</div>
    <div class="five common">e</div>
    <div class="six common">f</div>
    <div class="seven common">g</div>
    <div class="eight common">h</div>
    <div class="nine common">i</div>
    <div class="ten common">j</div>
    <div class="different"></div>
  </div>
```

then the above javascript can be modified like this

```
const parentDiv = document.querySelector('.grid');

const allDivs = parentDiv.querySelectorAll('div.color');

allDivs.forEach((div, i) => {
  div.style.backgroundImage=`url(/images/items/${year}/${i}.jpg')`;
})
```

the above code will pick only those `divs` which has `color` class added to it.

Comment: Thank you for the help!